# RunnerClass not locating steps?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber

Why is my runner class not locating my step file?

I have created two feature files with unique methods etc, if i execute them one by one they are able to locate the relevant steps, but dosnt work when executing the main runner class?

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions (
        features = {"src/test/java/CucumberFramework/featureFiles/"},
        glue = {"src/test/java/CucumberFramework/steps"},
        monochrome = true,
        tags = {},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json", "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/report.html"}
        )

public class MainRunner {

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `glue` takes a package name, not a path. So you would want:

```
@CucumberOptions (
        features = {"src/test/java/CucumberFramework/featureFiles/"},
        glue = {"CucumberFramework.steps"}, // < I changed this
        monochrome = true,
        tags = {},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json", "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/report.html"}
        )
```